# MYSQL | Get two different records from single table

Tags: mysql, database

Ok. This is kind of complicated.. I have been trying to achieve it and got no where so far.

I have three tables.
leave_approval
leave_applications
ml_leave_type

Here is leave_approval Table
[image]

which is then linked to leave_application from leave_application_id
[image]

Now here comes the Tricky Question, 
i want two records from table.

> 1. I want Total leaves taken by employee in year 2014
> 2. I want Total Leaves taken by employee in month november of 2014

so means need two columns with two different approaches yearly and monthly.

i have query so far.

```
SELECT 
  LA.employee_id,
  DATEDIFF(
    LA.approved_to,
    LA.approved_from
  ) AS TotalLeavesTaken,
  LAPP.`entitlement_id`,
  LAPP.`ml_leave_type_id`,
  LA.leave_application_id,
  LA.approved_from AS LeaveFrom,
  LA.approved_to AS LeaveTo 
FROM
  leave_approval LA 
  INNER JOIN leave_application LAPP 
    ON LAPP.application_id = LA.leave_application_id 
WHERE YEAR(LA.approval_date) = 2014
  AND LA.`employee_id` = 1
```

and here is the result i am getting for the query..
[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

**UPDATE**

May i could not clearly explain my problem.

What i am trying to achieve is add two extra columns not remove the columns i have. i mean i am using most/All of the select fields i have

Plus i want the Total Leaves in Year 2014 in one column and Total Leaves in the month in different field for that given year.

so here is kind of example i want.>

```
ml_leave_type_id | Total Leaves Taken in Year (e-g 2014) | Total Leaves taken in Month (e-g November)
     1                          10                                 2
     2                           6                                 0
     3                           4                                 1
```

Comment: No pics thanks. Just proper DDLs!!

Answer (score 0):

Edit2: updated select statement after requirements clarified. The update consist of reorganizing with using a JOIN instead of UNION ALL

```
select a.*, b.*
from (
    SELECT 
      LA.employee_id,
      DATEDIFF(
        LA.approved_to,
        LA.approved_from
      ) AS TotalLeavesTaken,
      LAPP.`entitlement_id`,
      LAPP.`ml_leave_type_id`,
      LA.leave_application_id,
      LA.approved_from AS LeaveFrom,
      LA.approved_to AS LeaveTo
    FROM
      leave_approval LA 
      INNER JOIN leave_application LAPP 
        ON LAPP.application_id = LA.leave_application_id 
    WHERE YEAR(LA.approval_date) = 2014
      AND LA.`employee_id` = 1 
) a

JOIN (
    SELECT 
      LA.employee_id,
      DATEDIFF(
        LA.approved_to,
        LA.approved_from
      ) AS TotalLeavesTaken,
      LAPP.`entitlement_id`,
      LAPP.`ml_leave_type_id`,
      LA.leave_application_id,
      LA.approved_from AS LeaveFrom,
      LA.approved_to AS LeaveTo 
    FROM
      leave_approval LA 
      INNER JOIN leave_application LAPP 
        ON LAPP.application_id = LA.leave_application_id 
    WHERE MONTHNAME(LA.approval_date) = 'November'
      AND LA.`employee_id` = 1
) b
ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id
```

Comment: Thankyou for reply, but you used SUM and i want to sum for idividual leave types. 
I mean there are leave types if you see in application.
so i do not want to sum those all leave types. i want to get the sum for every individual leave type.
e-g there are three leaves approvals for sick and 2 leave approvals for casual .
So i want the sum of three leave approvals which may be 10 days and 2 leave approvals which might be 4 days.. i know i am getting confusing let me update the question..

Comment: @SizzlingCode, I modified the answer after the question update / requirements updated. Please try the query and let us know if this fits your needs. I cannot test it since you didn't provided any sample data in an easy-to-work-with format. The query can be improved and made more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like that do?

Total leaves for employee_id = 1, Year 2014

```
SELECT 
  LA.employee_id,
  SUM(
     DATEDIFF(
      LA.approved_to,
      LA.approved_from
     )
  ) AS TotalLeavesTaken,
  LAPP.`entitlement_id`,
  LAPP.`ml_leave_type_id`,
  LA.leave_application_id,
  LA.approved_from AS LeaveFrom,
  LA.approved_to AS LeaveTo 
FROM
  leave_approval LA 
  INNER JOIN leave_application LAPP 
    ON LAPP.application_id = LA.leave_application_id 
WHERE YEAR(LA.approval_date) = 2014
  AND LA.`employee_id` = 1
GROUP BY LA.`employee_id` = 1
```

Total leaves for employee_id = 1, Year = 2014 AND Month = 11

```
SELECT 
  LA.employee_id,
  SUM(
     DATEDIFF(
      LA.approved_to,
      LA.approved_from
     )
  ) AS TotalLeavesTaken,
  LAPP.`entitlement_id`,
  LAPP.`ml_leave_type_id`,
  LA.leave_application_id,
  LA.approved_from AS LeaveFrom,
  LA.approved_to AS LeaveTo 
FROM
  leave_approval LA 
  INNER JOIN leave_application LAPP 
    ON LAPP.application_id = LA.leave_application_id 
WHERE YEAR(LA.approval_date) = 2014
  AND MONTH(LA.approval_date) = 11
  AND LA.`employee_id` = 1
GROUP BY LA.`employee_id` = 1
```

I do notice in your dataset however that there are some dates that are ovelapping. For example:

employee_id = 1 is on leave 2014/11/01 - 2014/11/06 AND 2014/11/05 - 2014/11/08. What's the deal with the dates 2014/11/05 and 2014/11/06. How will the system handle this scenario

Comment: Yes it is actually the dummy entries. xD. but dates for employee 1 is ok. so thats why i want to work with employee 1 :)